# preg_replace function set but not working

Tags: php, preg-replace

I GET IT WORKING, sorry guys...I should not put $_POST again inside the $stm

The below code is where I received the posted value for security purpose, i plan to put preg_replace function..but it is not working?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {

$customer_name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $_POST['customer_name']);
```

more code ...which might cause the problem? i checked my php it didn't filter

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {

$customer_name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', $_POST['customer_name']);
$tel_num = $_POST['tel_num'];
$customer_address = $_POST['customer_address'];
$error_status = false;

if (empty($_POST['customer_name'])){
echo '<a href="cart.php">Please Fill Your Name</a>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($_POST['tel_num'])){
echo '</br><a href="cart.php">Please Fill Your Contact Number</a></br>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($_POST['customer_address'])){
echo'<a href="cart.php">Please Fill Your Address</a></br>';
$error_status = true;
}

if(!$error_status) {

$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (customer_name,tel_num,customer_address,product_name, price, quantity, date_added,customer_messages) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_POST["item_name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $_POST['customer_name'],$_POST['tel_num'],$_POST['customer_address'], $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i],$_POST['customer_messages']);
$stmt->execute();
}
 ;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this regex ?

Comment: How do you know it does not work? What errors, what results did you get?

Comment: only allow A-Z ,a-z and 0-9?

Comment: I tested and submit this random data "%^&abdavavdbfbgFFDS" but it still show as "%^&abdavavdbfbgFFDS" in my database under myPHP admin

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it is going past the "if (isset($_POST['cartOutput']))" statement? How do you know it is not working? Do you see errors?

Comment: This is crazy. If I were you, I'd reconsider why it's a security risk to have a customer called `González` and how renaming him to `Gonzlez` can be considered a fix.

Comment: so what do you recommend? I just thought the hacker might put some code inside the text field and query/echo out my data

Comment: How exactly? Do you try to execute the customer name as code? What programming language only accepts non-English letters as commands?

Comment: yea so called sql injection? i ain't sure, all i know is using preg_replace, it is safer. Also using preg_replace just my first test, i certainly will put it on all text field. Tell me what else should i do to increase my site security?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: erm..seem like i worried too much then

<?php
$websiteUrl = $_REQUEST['url'];
if (!preg_match("#^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}#i",$websiteUrl)) {
echo "wrong url";
} else {
echo "ok";
}
?>
If i put the above code in all my file..is this useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine to me! Maybe check that customer_name has a value first?

```
$text = "h^&%*ello";
$new = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $text);
echo $new;

output: hello
```

When testing here http://writecodeonline.com/php/ I get the correct result so the syntax looks fine! Try ensuring there is a value!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a php script:

```
$customer_name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', '!h#e$l%l^o');
var_dump($customer_name);
```

And the result is:

```
string(5) "hello"
```

Please debug your codes to check `$_POST['customer_name']` content

Comment: should I add preg_replace inside the $stmt also?